# FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'ResourceBundle' not found

Tags: symfony, resourcebundle, intl, sonata-user-bundle

I installed and configured FOSUserBundle, SonataAdminBundle, SonataUserBundle, SonataMediaBundle correctly as written in here http://tech.dupeu.pl/2013/07/symfony-2-3-sonataadminbundle-sonatamediabundle-sonatauserbundle-and-fosuserbundle-a-good-project-base/ and with some research it's fine and I already can create a user, a superadmin etc..

Also Media ans Groups features works correctly ! I have a problem when tryin to add a user in the Admin Dashbord, I donnow exactly what it is about .. I searched on forums and on stackoverflow and it seems that it has a relation with SonataIntlBundle so I reinstalled it and I activated intl extension in my WampServer (Windows 8) but it's not working anymore ..

This is the error ( FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'ResourceBundle' not found in C:\wamp\www\project\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\Reader\BinaryBundleReader.php line 32 )

---

#### Solved

I fixed the problem by installing symfony/intl with composer : I added this "symfony/intl": "2.6.*@dev" to requiere section then I lunched the composer update command and now it's working !

You can check this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html for more informations!

Comment: install PECL extension  and ICU library

Answer (score 1):

ResourceBundle is a dependency of intl extension, so your intl or ICU version are wrong. Search for the right version (Thread Safe or not, 32bit or 64bit).
On WAMP is hard to found the right version. If I remember, when I had this issue, I had to downgrade my WAMP version.

Comment: My WAMPServer version is 2.4 on Windows8 32bits, how to know if intl or icu version is wrong or if they are thread safe or not ? I used to add them to require section in composer.json manually and then run the composer update command .. here is my composer.json require section :

Comment: "require": { "php": ">=5.3.3", "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*", "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev", "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.3.*@dev", "twig/extensions": "1.0.*", "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*", "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*", "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*", "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*", "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*", "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*", "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0", "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle" : "dev-master", "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master", "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "dev-master",

Comment: "sonata-project/exporter": "1.3.3", "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master", "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master", "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master", "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master", "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*@dev", "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.2.*@dev", "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.*", "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master", "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master", "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2", "sylius/resource": "0.10.*@dev", "sylius/resource-bundle": "0.10.*@dev",

Comment: Just run the PHP function "phpinfo()" and search for "TS" (Thread Safe) or "NTS" (Non Thread Safe).